# Query cursor Question

Tags: query, concurrency

Have a query regarding Query Cursor.

There are two limits that I see for Maximum number of query cursors open concurrently per user in the limits cheatsheet doc.

i)  50 for Apex Transactions.
ii) 10 for API

So If I have APEX REST Endpoint exposed to a client which makes query in Salesforce through related apex. Would that be counted as part of #1 or #2 ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to link to the docs you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

The 10 concurrent cursor "API" limit refers to direct API access, including calling `/tooling/query`, `/query`, etc. When you call Apex for any reason, including `/tooling/executeAnonymous`, and `/apexrest/`, you get the higher 50 cursor limit.